# How to load PresentationFramework into my xUnit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reference, .net-assembly, xunit

Actually it is very hard to search the web for similar cases. So I decided to ask here.

In my test project my SUT has reference to `PresentationFramework`from `Assembly` reference tag, and target framework is `.NET Framework 4.8`.

As I am using `xUnit`, my target framework is `.NET Core 2.2` and when running my tests I am getting test message:

> Message: System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or
>   assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

Actually I am not sure how to add `PresentationFramework` to `.NET Core`, or maybe I am supposed to change test project's target framework to `.NET Framework 4.8`?

Comment: .NET Core code cannot directly interface with .NET Framework code. Hence it is impossible for your .NET Core project to load assemblies from your .NET Framework project. The target Runtime Frameworks must be same in both projects, so if you change the Unit Test project Target framework to .NET Framework it should work

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I modified the csproj of the xunit test project to specify Windows SDK and WPF

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case it turned out that my unit test had the following dependencies:

```
UnitTest (netcoreapp2.2) -> Project_1 (netstandard2.0) -> Project_2 (net461)
```

Unit test (netcoreapp2.2) implicitly referenced to net461 project. I made Project_2 of type netstandard2.0. And so error disappeared.